# Em R, Usando dplyr, criar uma nova matriz

Tags: r, dplyr

Suponha que eu tenha a seguinte base de dados

```
 >data
   zona  candidato votos
    1     A         100
    1     B          20
    2     A          30
    2     B          15
```

Eu quero, usando dplry, a seguinte matriz

```
   >nova

   zona  votos_zona   votosA  votosB
     1      120         100       20
     2      45           30       15
```

Tentei algo assim

```
 nova <- data %>%
                     group_by(zona) %>%
                     summarise(votos_zona= sum(votos), 
                               votosA =      ,
                               votosB =         )
```

Mas não consigo completar o código

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aqui eu acho que cabe usar outra função de um outro pacote do Hadley, o `tidyr`.

```
require(tidyr)
data %>% spread(candidato, votos)

  zona   A  B
1    1 100 20
2    2  30 15
```

Observe que se você tiver diversos nomes de candidato, você não terá que digitar um por um.

```
> data <- data.frame(zona = c(1,1,1,1), candidato = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), votos = c(100,20,30,15))
> data
  zona candidato votos
1    1         A   100
2    1         B    20
3    1         C    30
4    1         D    15
> data %>% spread(candidato, votos)
  zona   A  B  C  D
1    1 100 20 30 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar a condição dentro da soma:

```
data %>% group_by(zona) %>%summarise(votos_zona = sum(votos),
                                     votosA = sum(votos[candidato=="A"]),
                                     votosB = sum(votos[candidato=="B"]))
Source: local data frame [2 x 4]

  zona votos_zona votosA votosB
1    1        120    100     20
2    2         45     30     15
```

Comment: Gostei da solução ... ela serve até para somar outras variáveis em relação aos candidatos. Obrigado

Comment: ontem rodei o codigo e deu tudo certo... hoje quando rodei de novo, aparece uma matriz de uma linha só... é como se não tivesse usado o group_by(zona)... me deu somente a soma total de cada variável que eu pedi:    votos_zona votosA votosB
1        165    130     35

Comment: @Vasco por algum motivo você carregou o `dplyr` primeiro e depois o pacote `plyr` em segundo. Quando você faz isso dá erro porque a função `summarise` do `plyr` mascara a função do `dplyr`. Reinicia o R e carrega somente o `dplyr` ou carrega **primeiro** o `plyr`e depois o `dplyr` (nessa ordem). Veja essa questão do SOen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106146/using-dplyr-to-summarise-by-group/26106218#26106218